# How to find $A^{100}$ by using the Cayley Hamilton theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations, cayley-hamilton

How to find $A^{100}$ as a linear function of *A* by use of the **Cayley Hamilton theorem**?

The characteristic equation leads to $A^2-4A+3I=0$. I can't find any way to solve this.

Comment: $A^2=4A-3I \implies A^4 = 4A^3-3A^2= \cdots$. Put the value of $A^2$ in right hand side. and go on.

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: Note that $A^2=4A-3I$ reduces the powers of $A$ from the left to the right and side. Use this to repeatedly substitute the later half for the former while you build up powers of $A$ by multiplying through by $A^2$ and simplifying @TRUSKI  did until you have $A^{100}$ in terms of $A$.

Comment: What's happening here that everyone is just commenting the answers, instead of just posting it as an answer?

Comment: Again hint. See http://clay6.com/qa/18769/matrix-a-satisfies-a-2-2a-i-where-i-is-the-identity-matrix-then-for-n-32a-n

Comment: @leena is the answer below sweet you?

Answer (score 4):

> **Answer** $$\color{blue}{~~ A^{100}  =\frac12(3^{100}-1)(A -I)~~+~~I}$$

**Blatant way of doing.**

$$A^2 =4A-3I \implies A^{100 } = A^{2*50}  =(4A-3I)^{50}$$

that is by Binomial formula I have,  $$A^{100 } =(4A-3I)^{50} =\sum_{j=0}^{50} {50\choose j }3^{50-j}4^j A^j$$
From here you get the result by induction. But I guess it is Harder and studios.

> **General setting**
>   In a more general setting.
>
> **Problem** I want to compute $A^n$ for all $n$ given that $A^2 =4A-3I $

Let $X_n =A^n$. Then 
$$X_{n+2} =A^{n+2} =A^{n}A^2 = A^n(A-3I) = 4X_{n+1} -3X_n$$

Hence we have the recurssive relation $$\color{blue}{X_{n+2} =4X_{n+1} -3X_n\Longleftrightarrow X_{n+2}-X_{n+1} =3(X_{n+1} -X_n) }$$

By Hence $(X_{n+1} -X_n)_n$ is a geometric sequence with coefficient 3 
so that,

$$\color{blue}{ X_{n+1}-X_{n} =3^n(X_{1} -X_0) =3^n(A -I)}$$

Thus for very $n$
$$\color{red}{\forall~n,~~~ X_{n+1}-X_{n}  =3^n(A -I) \implies X_n -X_0 = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(X_{j+1}-X_j)  =(A -I)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}3^j }$$

But, $$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}3^j =\frac{3^n-1}{3-1}=  \frac12(3^n-1)$$

Finally since $X_n =A^n $ we have, 
$$\color{red}{\forall~n,~~ A^n  =\frac12(3^n-1)(A -I)~~+~~I}$$

Particularly for n$ n =100 $
$$\color{blue}{~~ A^{100}  =\frac12(3^{100}-1)(A -I)~~+~~I}$$

Comment: I would agree this is a nice problem. Your solution might be streamlined by $A \begin{pmatrix} A \\ I\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 4& -3 \\ 1& 0 \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} A \\ I\end{pmatrix}$, where the matrix diagonalizes trivially to diag(3,1), and raised to the 100th power to then readily recompose to your answer.

Comment: Ok you want to make it complicate. How will you compute the nth power of the matrices? through the eigenspaces and eigenvalue techniques isn't? this make the process longer that the current solution.  i am currios to see how you can your relation to a power.

Comment: $M=  \begin{pmatrix}
      4&-3\\
      1&0
    \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}
      3&1\\
      1&1
    \end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix}
      3&0\\
      0&1
    \end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix}
      1&-1\\
      -1&3
    \end{pmatrix} /2 =V^{-1}MV$ , so the nth power is $V^{-1}M^nV = \begin{pmatrix}
      3^{n+1}-1&-3^{n+1}+3\\
      3^n-1&-3^n+3
    \end{pmatrix} /2$.

Comment: The above method avoid this usage of  diagonalisation to compute the power. it take more time